# How do I make my DAPP compatible with MIST?

Tags: web3js, mist, dapp-development

I have created a [small DAPP](http://governmental.github.io/GovernMental/) and it works fine with a geth rpc node running. However - I want to make it also compatible with the current MIST version (the November developer release)

It seems like there are [different options](https://gist.github.com/frozeman/fbc7465d0b0e6c1c4c23) to include the web3 object. I have chosen this one:

```
// 2. optional use web3 from mist, OR load if outside of mist
  if(typeof web3 === 'undefined')
     web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

So my assumption is: if the DAPP is loaded within MIST web3 does already exist and is not overwritten.
However - It still does not work and I get a:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

So the question is: what are the steps to make a DAPP compatible with MIST?

Answer (score 3):

`web3` is already present in Mist, but not `Web3`, so you would use the provider of the web3 object and use your own Web3 version you added from your package:

```
 if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined')
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```